# Test ng-click handler on anchor tag

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, protractor

I've got a regular (non JS) anchor tag that links to an external site, but with additional behaviour to perform on click that changes the DOM

```
<body ng-controller="MyController">
  <a href="https://www.google.co.uk/" ng-click="inProgress = true">
    {{ inProgress ? "Going to Google" : "Go to Google" }}
  </a>
</body>
```

I would like to test this behaviour in an E2E protractor test. However, it looks like once the link is clicked, subsequent commands are run in the context of the external page. For example, the following test passes:

```
browser.element(by.css('a')).click();
expect(browser.getCurrentUrl()).toBe('https://www.google.co.uk/');
```

but the following test fails

```
browser.element(by.css('a')).click();
expect(browser.element(by.css('body')).getText()).toBe('Going to Google');
```

with the failure shows the content of the Google home page as the text of `body`.

How can I test what happens after a click on a non-Javascript `a` tag?

Comment: Add _blank target if you want your link to open on a different window, otherwise the test is correct to fail, you html disappear when you click on the link

Comment: @floribon At the moment, I don't want the link to open in a new window, but I do want to test that the user sees the text change in the link after they click it.

Comment: you could use JQuery triggerHandler and test this scenario. `browser.element('a').triggerHandler('click')`

Comment: @RameshkumarArumugam Sounds like that has potential. Add as an answer? (However, the app I'm testing doesn't include jQuery)

Answer (score 1):

I suppose you need to wait for the text to change after the click happens. From your code, you are looking for the text *immediately* after the click? Have you tried [Expected Conditions](http://www.protractortest.org/#/api?view=ExpectedConditions)

```
var EC = protractor.ExpectedConditions;
browser.wait(EC.textToBePresentInElement($('body'), 'Going to Google'), 5000);
```

Comment: Expected conditions don't help.  Testing *immediately* after the click shows the external page has loaded, so waiting longer won't turn the clock back and give protractor access to what is at that point the previous page.

Comment: Oh sorry I misunderstood. I thought you are testing the body content of the subsequent page

Comment: Reading through the question again, I feel EC still has potential, although not entirely promising. You are testing for the body text _immediately_ but maybe you need to wait for a fraction of a second and give protractor a chance?

Comment: I'm still unsure how that would help... A chance to do what?

Comment: At the risk of stating the obvious, WebDriverJS (protractor uses that internally) polls for EC every poll duration (default I think is 500ms). In above example, the final timeout is 5s and each poll duration is 500ms. After 5s, protractor will throw timeout exception. What I was saying was maybe during the poll duration of 500ms, protractor may have a chance to see the body text flipping